# Minify Javascript to Early Edition

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert minimized java script to early Edition?

```
Is any software or website for this work?
```

Thank u for hints.

Comment: Did you google? [minify and unminify javascript](https://www.google.com.np/search?q=minify+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=94YiU_zuCI6WrAeK-YDYBA#channel=fflb&q=minify%20and%20unminify%20javascript&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official)

Comment: yes I didn,t found any positive thing

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no `software` to `unminify javascript` you can minify it but reversing is not possible, if you are creating your own javascript code then you must keep both javascript versions `minified` and `unminified` for future reference.
And if you are using a `javascript library or framework` then both `versions (minified and unminified)` will be available on that `site`.

Comment: You're confusing minifying with obfuscating. You can indeed beautify your code, in fact, there are lots of them in the web. Obfuscating, however is not possible, atleast not to my knowledge. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @shriek Yes you can `beautify js code` but minified versions contains short code and long variable names are converted in short like `a,b,c,d,....` and if you are converting it again in unminified version that means to convert `a,b,c,d,...` to its `original variable` with beautifier. See both version [jquery-unminified](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js) and [jquery-minified](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js)

Comment: It's because jquery uses both minification and obfuscation. Minifying code doesn't necessarily mean obfuscating. Minifying just means removing white space characters, new line characters, comments etc. `UglifyJS and YUI Compressor` does both and this is what `jquery` is doing in it's minfied version.

Comment: Exactly, if you are using any compression software to compress then it will provide you both `minification and obfuscation` so you can unminified it but how you will remove the obfuscations, Compile the demo given on http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home. So pure `unminification` is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot be "unminified". The purpose of minification is to represent the original javascript in the least number of characters. However it is a one way transformation since there are no clues in the minified version that can lead you back to the original content.

Ex: the variable `myLongVariableName` can be minified to just `a` since the JavaScriupt interpreter doesn't care about human readable variable names. However, after it's been mapped to `a` there is no way to map it back to `myLongVariableName`